# JAVA Algorithm for a function that prints 3 element subsets?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, printing

I got a question and I am writing an algorithm for that. I am given the first line which is int Print-3-element-subsets(int n, int s[]). My algorithm doesn't seem correct. Please help me.

Write a function that prints out all 3-element subsets of the elements in array S (indexed from 1 to n). don’t print the same subset twice, and make sure each subset has exactly 3 elements.

```
int Print-3-element-subset(int n, int s[])
{
    for(int i =0; i<n; i++)

         for(int j=n; j<i; j--)

            for(int k =n ; k<i; j--)

                print("{"+s[i]+ ", "+s[j]+"," +s[k]+"}");
}
```

Comment: This wont even compile. Check your method name.

Comment: *"Write a function that prints out all 3-element subsets of the elements in array S (indexed from 1 to n)"* Arrays in Java are indexed starting with 0, not 1. And if whoever "gave" you the first line is meant to be teaching you Java, I would find a new teacher.

Comment: @Aniket Thakur thanks for your response on my code. Yes I know. I am not trying to write a complete code and compile it but, i am just trying to write the algorithm(pseudo code) for the question.

Comment: You need to apply some basic logic to your problem. For instance: Your outermost loop starts with `i = 0` and continues as long as `i` is less than `n`. But then the loop within it starts with `j = n` and continues as long as `j` is less than `i`. But if `j` starts with `n`, `j` will **never** be less than `i`, because `i` is guaranteed by your outermost loop to be less than `n`. Rather than jumping into code or pseudo code, maybe get out a pencil and paper and work through the indexes manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
void print3elementSubsets(int[] s) {
    int n = s.length;
    for(int i = 0; i < n-2; i++) {
        for(int j = i+1; j < n-1; j++) {
            for(int k = j+1 ; k < n; k++) {
                print("{"+s[i]+ ", "+s[j]+"," +s[k]+"}");
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

If you have such a problem, first use paper and pencil in order to get the indexes right. Draw the array, think about where `i` should start and end, etc. Don't jump right into programming and try to "tweak" the code until it fits.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should also work for small subsets

```
void printThreeElementSubsets(int[] s) {
    int n = s.length;
    for (int mask = 0; mask < (1 << n); ++mask) {
        if (Integer.bitCount(mask) == THREE) {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
                if ((mask & (i << 1)) != 0)
                    System.out.print(s[i] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

And it guarantees that the subset is printed only once.